# I have following policy types how will be the RUTA script for it, by using which i will be able to extract complete policy number

Tags: ruta, pega

Policy id has following variations

Policy id : V 123455
Policy id : V123455
Policy id : V123 455

extraction value  should be V123455

I tried using below RUTA script
W{REGEXP("(?i)(V|A)")}
REGEXP("^((?:\s*\d){3,6})$") -> MARK(EntityType,1,2);